# Setting widget values programmatically in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it possible to set the current "value" of a bokeh widget programmatically ?

My intention is to implement an url handler for urls like `http://127.0.0.1/<device_id>` to set the active item in an `Select` widget to `<device_id>`.